# Find all lines not ending with a pattern

Tags: c#

I've a list of lines from which I'd like to select only the ones that end with the pattern "XE"

Answer (score 3):

```
lines.Where(l => l.EndsWith("XE"));
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try this

```
List<string> myString = new List<string>(); // whatever your list
myString= myString.Where(a => a.EndsWith("XE")).ToList();
```

Answer (score -1):

```
List<string> resList = origList.Where(x => x.EndsWith("XE"))
```

Comment: This does not compile. LINQ deals with `IEnumerable`. You can either use `var` or `IEnumerable<string>` or use `.ToList()`

Comment: Yeah you're right but the general idea is there...and the ";" is also missing :)